# Loops does not close at their right place

Tags: algorithm2e

I am trying to write an algorithm on laTex, my problem is that for loops do not close at right place. I am printing output outside of loop but still it appears inside for loop

```
 \title{AlgorithmTemplate}
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \text{X$\{x : \ x \in\ I \}$}
    {$Y1(x,  i\textsubscript{k}) \\
    $Y2$ ($x$,  i\textsubscript{k}) \\
    $Y3$ ($x$,  i\textsubscript{k}) \\
    $Y4$ ($x$,  i\textsubscript{k}) \\
        \For{each {i \in\ Y\ }}{
            \For{ each {x \in\ Z }}{
            \statement{$Y1$ ($x$,  i\textsubscript{k})} \leftarrow {\{i \in  Y \ :\ } \{x, i {k}\} 
            \statement {$Y2$  ($x$,  i\textsubscript{k}})\\ 
            \statement {$Y3$ ($x$,i\textsubscript{k})} \leftarrow {\{i \in  Y \ : \ } \ \frac{| x\ \cap \  i\textsubscript{k} |}{|x\ \cup \ i\textsubscript{k} |}\\
           \statement {$Y4$ ($x$,i\textsubscript{k})} \leftarrow{\{i\in Y\ : }\ \frac{| x\ \cap\ i\textsubscript{k} |}{|x\ \cup \ i\textsubscript{k}|} > threshold \} \\ 
                 \If{x \in  XV \vee \ i \in VI}{
                 color that particular text\\
                 }\\
                \Else {
                default }
            }\\\\
        }\\
    {$Result \leftarrow Y1 (x, i\textsubscript {k}) + Y2 (x, i\textsubscript {k}) + Y3 (x, i\textsubscript {k}) + Y4 (x, i\textsubscript {k}$)}\\
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

Here is output

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your code is not compilable, please add the document class and packages used.

Comment: @AndréC Thank you so much for your reply. I used online overleaf.com to compile this code and it compiles.

Comment: Indeed, he compiles on overleaf, not with MikTeX.

Comment: @AndréC i pasted whole code here. It is running in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't know for sure what your initial intent was, but your code shows vast misunderstanding of the `algorithm2e` package commands, as well as basic LaTeX instructions. I believe even on Overleaf, you should have had multiple errors/warnings due to all these issues.

Here is a list of the various corrections :

- Checked for unclosed braces `{...}` most of them are useless in the statements you provided anyway so I removed them
- Checked for unclosed / unmatching `$...$`. Multiple were simply not closed. I merged math statements in some lines as it was simplify not required to use multiple ones
- Replaced `\textunderscript` in text mode with `\mathrm` in math mode.
- (Optional) Replaced `\leftarrow` with `\gets`
- Replaced newline instructions **which should not be used in `algorithm2e` algorithms to separate statements** with `\;` along with the `\DontPrintSemicolon` instruction
- Replaced `\For{each` with the actual `\ForEach` instruction provided by `algorithm2e` as well as the `\eIf` command for `If-Then-Else` constructs

You should have a look at the `algorithm2e` package documentation before furhter using its functionalities.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \text{X$\{x : \ x \in\ I \}$}
    $Y1(x,  i_\mathrm{k})$ \;
    $Y2(x,  i_\mathrm{k})$ \;
    $Y3(x,  i_\mathrm{k})$ \;
    $Y4(x,  i_\mathrm{k})$ \;
    \ForEach{$i \in\ Y$}{
        \ForEach{$x \in\ Z$}{
            $Y1(x,  i_\mathrm{k}) \gets \{i \in  Y : \{x, i {k}\}\}$\;
            $Y2(x,  i_\mathrm{k})$\;
            $Y3(x,i_\mathrm{k}) \gets \{i \in  Y : \frac{| x \cap i_\mathrm{k} |}{|x \cup i_\mathrm{k} |}\}$\;
            $Y4(x,i_\mathrm{k}) \gets \{i\in Y :  \frac{| x \cap i_\mathrm{k} |}{|x \cup i_\mathrm{k}|} > threshold \}$ \;
            \eIf{$x \in  XV \vee \ i \in VI$}{
                      color that particular text\;
                      }{
                     default }
                 }
        }
    $Result \leftarrow Y1 (x, i_\mathrm {k}) + Y2 (x, i_\mathrm {k}) + Y3 (x, i_\mathrm {k}) + Y4 (x, i_\mathrm {k}$)\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]